# How to set cordova to android target API 21

Tags: android, cordova

how can I set the minimum and target SDK version to 21?
So far I changed it inside the Android Manifest, but still the build process shows android SDK level 19.

Thanks

Comment: no I did not find a solution

Comment: How you are building the project? from eclipse or CLI?

Comment: I build the app from CLI

Answer (score 4):

As you say it doesn't react at all to changes in the manifest, you have to manually add a tag specifying the minimum sdk in the config.xml located in the project root folder.

> preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16"

Note that this will only work if you have updated to a Cordova version which supports the target sdk.

It is all answered here:
[Changing the android target of a cordova project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29542008/changing-the-android-target-of-a-cordova-project?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

With Cordova 3.5.something started to go wrong to set Cordova to android target API 21 this can be used:

```
<platform name="android">
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="21" />
</platform>
```

The advantage is that now you can delete the android platform and recreate it without losing any setting.