# Changing the android target of a cordova project

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

i'm new to cordova development and i created my first cordova project using this command as in following site
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html

```
 cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
```

After used these commands to add a platform to project,

```
 cd hello
 cordova platform add android
```

and command line gives these output

```
    Adding android project...
    Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:        
    Path: platforms\android
    Package: com.exampple.hell
    Name: helloWorld
    Android target: android-21
    Copying template files...
    Project successfully created.
```

according to this Android target of this project is android-21 but installed android SDK on my machine only has up to android API level 19. So when i import these project to eclipse IDE to make further changes to project it gives error on console

```
Unable to resolve target 'android-21'
```

I changed AndroidManifest.xml file as

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

but still have the problem.

can i change the android target to 19 when the platform is added to project or is there another way to fix this and run project with android API level 19

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should update your SDK on your machine first of all. The compatibility depends on your `config.xml` file content.

For example you want to support android levels from 16 to 19, then this part of the `config.xml` should look like this:

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16"/>
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="19"/>
```

The build method then takes care of `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: where can i find this config.xml ??one i found inside the project, it doesn't has a part like that.what should i do??

Comment: Yes, you have to add these lines yourself. :)

Comment: Thank you, that worked. additionally I had to change the  target=android-21 part of project.properties  file as target=android-19 which is located in platforms/android directory in order to build the project using android API level 19